# Create Queue from List C++

Tags: c++, list, stl, queue

Pretty simple task, but I have some errors, which I don't understand. The task is to create a function, that will return Queue from List(using STL)

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

queue<int> reverse(const list<int>& data) noexcept {
    queue <int> Queue;
    for (list<int>::reverse_iterator i = data.rbegin(); i != data.rend(); i++) {
        Queue.push(*i);
    }
    return Queue; 
}
```

Errors:

```
1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\xutility(1746,1): error C2664: 'std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>>::_List_iterator(const std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>> &)': cannot convert argument 1 from '_BidIt' to 'std::_List_iterator<std::_List_val<std::_List_simple_types<_Ty>>> &&'

1>C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.24.28314\include\xutility(1746,96): message: No user-defined-conversion operator available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be called
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data` is `const list<int>&`. You should use `const_reverse_iterator`.

```
queue<int> reverse(const list<int>& data) noexcept
{
    queue <int> Queue;
    for (list<int>::const_reverse_iterator i = data.crbegin(); i != data.crend(); i++)
    {
        Queue.push(*i);
    }
    return Queue; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Didn't know, that const_reverse_iterator even exists

Comment: @RomaRoik Now you know:)